# How to draw a horizontal-separator-line just under the first row?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table like this:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | // row1
| col1 | col2 | // row2
| col1 | col2 | // row3
+------+------+
```

Now I want to draw a line under `row1`. I can select it using this way:

```
tr:nth-child(1){ // selecting first row }
```

Or this way:

```
tr:first-child { // selecting first row }
```

But I don't know why `border-bottom` does not work in this case. Actually I want something like this:

```
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | // row1
+------+------+
| col1 | col2 | // row2
| col1 | col2 | // row3
+------+------+
```

It should be noted, other properties work as well, like this:

```
tr:first-child {
    color: red;                  // the color will be red
    border-bottom: 1px solid;    // it does not work
}
```

So, how can I do that?

Comment: could you please reproduce the issue in a fiddle or so..

Comment: @Lal I want to write a line under red-color text. http://jsfiddle.net/4n5vhu28/

Comment: Have you tried applying border-bottom, not to the `<tr>`, but rather, the children in the `<tr>`.  That is to say, trying adding `border-bottom` to the `<td>`. Also, proper short hand border CSS is `border-bottom: solid 1px black;`.

Comment: @AlexanderDixon So, how to select all `<td>`s in the first row?

Comment: @Sajad is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/4n5vhu28/1/) what you want?

Comment: @Lal yes. thanks. also there is an answer the same with what you did, anyway thanks pal :-)

Comment: Great.. :) Glad that you got it right.. :)

Comment: @Sajad, please see my answer below. `tr:first-child td`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following to your CSS:

```
table  {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Additional you have to set a color for your border: `border-bottom:1px solid red;`

The full example look like this:

```css
table  {
  border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr:first-child {
  color:red;                
  border-bottom:1px solid red;  
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>col1</td>
        <td>col2</td>
        <td>col3</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use thead and tbody for that.

```css
thead th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col1</th>
      <th>col2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>col1</td>
      <td>col2</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah it works. But I don't know why I don't like to use `thead`, anyway ok +1, If there is not any solution (without `thead`) I will mark your solution as the answer of my question.

Comment: You could give them a specific class like `.first-row` then you can separately style them too..

Comment: Also keep in mind that border-bottom doesn't work on the `tr` tag, only on the `td` tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can do specific pathing CSS targeting.

```css
tr:first-child td {
    border-bottom: solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>test</td>
        <td>test</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dixalex/4n5vhu28/2/)